# Bash FFMPEG - ".mp4 no such file or directory"

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to save an .asf stream to an mp4 on my Ubuntu machine with the output file name being a timestamp. Here's the code:

```
current_time=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y_%H:%M:%S")
ffmpeg -i http://username:password@IP:Port/videostream.asf -r 10 -vcodec copy -an -t 60 $current_time.mp4
```

However, I get an ".mp4 no such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `bash` does not allow to you create file-names with `/` present
>
> According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169) "[t]he characters composing the [file] name may be selected from the set of all character values **excluding the slash character** and the null byte". In other words, every string *between* two slashes ([except the empty string]) is another directory, and you *cannot* create a file with a name containing slashes.

Create it without the slashes,

```
ffmpeg -i http://username:password@IP:Port/videostream.asf -r 10 -vcodec copy -an -t 60 "${current_time//\//_}".mp4
```

(or) change your time string to not to have '/' in the timestmap,

```
current_time="$(date "+%m_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S")"
ffmpeg -i http://username:password@IP:Port/videostream.asf -r 10 -vcodec copy -an -t 60 "${current_time}".mp4
```